# Can not link elements from GStreamer library with function gst_element_link_many

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer

I created in main next elements and I am trying to link them to play video, but result of gst_element_link_many  is always FALSE.

```
GstElement *pipeline, *videosrc, *videoenc, *muxer, *sink;
 pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("video-player");
  videosrc = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "videosrc");
  muxer = gst_element_factory_make ("qtdemux", "mux");
  videoenc = gst_element_factory_make ("avdec_mpeg4", "videoenc");
  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "sink");

 g_object_set (G_OBJECT (videosrc), "location", argv[1], NULL);
 gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), videosrc, muxer, videoenc, sink, NULL);

  /* link the elements together */
  int resLinkMany = gst_element_link_many (videosrc, muxer, videoenc, sink, NULL);

  printf(" resLinkMany = %d \n", resLinkMany); //I get 0
```

In general I am trying to launch video, but it didn't work because of incorrect linking. Here is the full code of my program: https://pastebin.com/BER1BZDU

Comment: Use the GST_DEBUG environment variable to see the errors. Also try the command with gst-launch.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake - as you can see from `gst-inspect-1.0 qtdemux` the src-pads are 'sometimes' pads. You need to use the 'pad-added' signal to be able to link to them. gst-launch does this transparently.